# Dífference between: "Я знаю русский язык." and "Я говорю русский язык."?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

"Я знаю русский язык." and "Я говорю русский язык." is as I have understood it equal in meaning (please, correct me if I am wrong).

Today my tutor told me that: "Я говорю русский язык." is the preferred phrase to use.

I would prefer to use: "Я знаю русский язык" that is if they are equal in meaning. Let me know what you think and if there is a difference between these two.

Comment: "Я говорю русский язык." == "I speak, English language".
Just sounds so wrong

Comment: "Я говорю русский язык" is totally ungrammatical

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your tutor is wrong. The second option sounds incorrectly.
Correct options are:

> 1. Я владею русским (языком).
> 2. Я говорю по-русски.
> 3. Я знаю русский (язык).
> 4. Я говорю на русском (языке).

IMO: The first is the preferable one. The last is the worst.

As @Matt and @user907860 mentioned in comment, `Я говорю` has two meanings:

> I speak
>   [Now] I'm speaking

So options 2 and 4 can have another meaning in some circustances.

Comment: Which one is preferred the one with "знаю" or "говорю"? Is there a distinction between those two or are they absolutely equal in meaning?

Comment: I believe, the difference is the same as for English "to know" and "to speak". But their meanings in this context are the same.

Comment: Я говорю по-русски. is most natural imo

Comment: `Я говорю по-русски` is the preferred variant.

Comment: `The last is the worst` Not really. It just means the slightly different thing: "Я говорю на русском" = "[Now] I'm speaking Russian".

Comment: @Matt Indeed. Don't you mind if I add it to the answer?

Comment: @Dmitry Да без проблем.

Comment: the second item also has the meaning of *I'm speaking Russian*. From the edited version of the answer the OP can construe that **only** "the last has also another meaning", which is not true.

Comment: @user907860 Good point. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

"Я говорю русский язык" is absolutely incorrect. You should say

> Я говорю по-русски

or

> Я знаю русский язык